# running C++ code under Matlab using sge cluster?

Tags: c++, matlab, cluster-computing, sungridengine

i have a matlab code that run a c++ functions, it works well on my computer 
or any other desktop I've tried to run it on.
(in order to run it on other desktop i copied the matlab/c++ functions and the mex files)

lately I've  tried to run the code on a sge cluster but i get an error messege

"Undefined function 'img' for input arguments of type 'double'"

"img" is the c++ function called by matlab.

does anyone encountered the same problem? 
does anyone knows how to solve it?

10x
Elad

Comment: Are you sure that the mex file is 'visible' from the compute nodes on your cluster ?  On several of the clusters I've worked on installation of a library on the submit host (the machine on which you run `qsub` etc) did not make it accessible to processes on the compute nodes.  Consult your sys admins.

Comment: 10x for your respond, ill check it after i re-mex the functions to fit the sge platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have different OS on laptop/desktop and SGE. For different architectures you need to re-`mex` your c++ code.

Configure `mex` on your sge

```
>> mex -setup
```

I strongly recommend using `gcc`. Now you can `mex` your c++ code. Note that the file extension for the mex files is **different** on windows/sge as well as 32bit and 64bit systems.

If you don't have the right extension for the mex file (can be checked using `mexext` command) Matlab cannot find the function to run and you get an error sinilar to what you got.

Happy Chanukah.

Comment: Hi,
i didn't knew there are different mex files for every system, but it of course make sense.  

can i mex the files to be mexa64 from a windows64 platform or i most  have a linux system for it?

10x and Hag_Samech for you as well

Comment: @Dudas - you need to `mex` your files for each platform. Since `c++` compiler is not a big issue, you shouldn't find it too difficult to do.